# Every absolutely convergent series can be bounded by the harmonic series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be an arbitrary absolutely convergent series. Can we show that 
$$
\exists C>0 :  a_n \le  \frac{C}{n}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Define $a_n$ by saying that $a_n=0$ if $n$ is not a perfect cube, while $a_n=1/j^2$ if $n=j^3$. Then $\sum a_n=\sum1/j^2<\infty$, but if $n=j^3$ then $na_n=j$, so $na_n$ is not bounded.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.